# JavaScript Overriding HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I have been able to make some progress with my problem but have encountered something a little unexpected/confusing. I have been able to add my script to my web page, however, the two do not work together. Without the script, the page appears as I would like. With the script, the script runs and overrides the web page. What happens is a random picture shows up in the top left corner of the screen, but nothing from the html file appears. I have included all my code (html, javascript, css) and if anyone can provide some guidance it would be really greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="mplstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title>Monroe Public Library</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="pageContent">
        <div id="head">
            <img src="mpl.jpg" alt="Monroe Public Library" />
      </div>

        <div id="links">
            <ul class = "nav">
            <span>Quick Links</span>
            <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Online Catalog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Friends of MPL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Books and Other Good Reading</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ohio Virtual Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Public Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services and Collection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Adult Programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teen Central</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children's Room</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computers at MPL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computer Rules and Procedures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff Directory</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Library Records</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
        <h2>Library Records</h2>
            <p>To view the library records, enter your username and password.</p>

            <form id="login" method="post" action="">
                <p>
                    <label for="username" class="center" id="input"> Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="center" id="input"> Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="captcha" id="input">As a final security check, enter the 5 numbers you see displayed below.</label>
                    <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" size="6" />
              </p>
              <p id="login">&nbsp;</p>
              <p id="login">
              </p>
              <script src="mpl.js"></script>

          <p align="center"><img src="" alt="" name="number1" width="70" height="100" id="number1"><img src="" alt="" name="number2" width="70" height="100" id="number2"><img src="" alt="" name="number3" width="70" height="100" id="number3"><img src="" alt="" name="number4" width="70" height="100" id="number4"><img src="" alt="" name="number5" width="70" height="100" id="number5"></p>
                <div id="images">
  </div>
                <p align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="View Library Records" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="address">
            <span class="addressBold">Monroe Public Library</span>
            580 Main Street, Monroe, OH &nbsp;&nbsp;45050
            <span class="addressBold">Phone</span>(513) 555-0211
            <span class="addressBold">Fax</span>(513) 555-0241
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

window.onload = function ()
{
        //http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Random-Image-Script.phtml
        var pictureNumbers=new Array()
        //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
        pictureNumbers[1]="0.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[2]="1.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[3]="2.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[4]="3.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[5]="4.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[6]="5.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[7]="6.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[8]="7.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[9]="8.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[10]="9.jpg"

        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*pictureNumbers.length)

        if (randomNumber==0)
        {
            randomNumber=1
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==1)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==2)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==3)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==4)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==5)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==6)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==7)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==8)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==9)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        else if (randomNumber==10)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
    }


@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body
{
    margin-top:0;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background-color:#FFC;
}

#head
{
    background-color:orange;
}

#page
{
    width: auto;
    margin" 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: none;
}

#links
{
    position:absolute;
    width:10em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    top: 72px;
    background-color: white;
}

#main
{
    margin-left: 12em;
}

#login
{
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#address
{
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

#pageContent #main h2 {
    color: #00F;
}

#input
{
    background-color: orange;
    padding-right: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have lots of conditional branches which all do the same exact thing?

Comment: I guess you just pasted all your code there and that you code isn't actually that.

Comment: Don't use document.write

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is, can you elaborate?  What do you mean by "nothing from the HTML file appears"?  If you step through the code in your browser's debugger, at what point does it behave differently than you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is document.write. You should either be creating an element and appending it to a parent element in the DOM, or changing the src attribute of an existing element.

#### Creating Elements and appending them

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent"),
    img = document.createElement("img")

img.setAttribute("src","your-file-name.jpg")
parent.appendChild(img)
```

### Example

Here is a simplified example of what you are doing.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/L3WYH/1/

#### HTML

```
<div id="picture-frame"></div>
```

#### JS

```
var pictureNumbers = [],
    pictureCount = 10

for ( var i = 1; i <= pictureCount; i++ )
    pictureNumbers[i] = i + ".jpg"

var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(pictureNumbers.length - 1)),
    element = document.getElementById("picture-frame"),
    image = document.createElement("img")

image.setAttribute("src", pictureNumbers[randomNumber])
element.appendChild(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Gary's comment to the original post:

The calls to `document.write(...)` are what's causing your problem. Upon firing the 'onload' event, the browser closes the document for writing. Any subsequent calls to `document.write` will literally overwrite the whole page.

To fix this, you will need to do one of two things:

1. Make your calls to `document.write` outside of the window.onload event
2. Do as @MBottens mentioned in his answer, where you append new `<img>` elements to a DIV tag.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I do not really understand your code. I know that you are providing me with something that should be obvious but I am new to this and I simply do not understand. Could you possibly explain a little bit of the code???

Comment: If you have `document.write`'s in the middle of your HTML (ie they execute while the page is being rendered), they'll work as expected.  If you call `document.write` after the page is loaded (which is exactly what window.onload does), then it overwrites the entire document with that line.  The solution is to create the elements and append them to where they need to go.  You need to learn about the Document Object Model (DOM) and how to use it.